# Apache camel consumer

Tags: apache-camel

i have  a camel consumer defined by :

```
 from("direct:Geonames")
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD,constant("GET"))
    .to("http://api.geonames.org/search?q=${body}&username=user")
    .log("response received :${body}");
```

i call this consumer to get all the cities that have the name that is sent in the body

```
 pt.sendBody("direct:Geonames","paris");
```

the problem is that i get the cities that have name body instead of paris

Comment: See this FAQ: http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-to.html

Answer (score 0):

Your expectation about dynamic endpoint address in to(endpoint address) is not right.

Call recipientList() that calculate enpoint address at runtime

Try instead of

```
to("http://api.geonames.org/search?q=${body}&username=user")
```

use

```
recipientList(simple("http://api.geonames.org/search?q=${body}&username=user"))
```